# Библиотеки контролов для Android

Tags: android, компоненты

Стандартный набор контролов Android довольно скуден. Их, конечно, можно переделать, но меня мучает вопрос. Есть ли готовые наборы контролов (типа, как библиотеки компонент в Delphi)? Google навел только на [это](https://github.com/commonsguy/), я его еще не посмотрел, но этого явно мало.

Вообще меня интересует элемент как на [видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-2c3rf0uPI#at=25). Там ребята управляют роботами с планшета, для управления шасси. Используется что-то вроде виртуального джойстика - тыкнул пальцем фишку на экране, и таскаешь ее в пределах круглой области. Вот мне такое нужно.
Если кто видел - прошу.

Answer (score 5):

Интересно! А чем же набор стандартных контролов так скуден? Стандартных контролов за глаза хватает и это лучший способ писать приложения, нежели сидеть писать велосипеды и терять время на ненужные вещи. Выше правильно Вам ответили. То что Вы хотите - джойстик, используемый в играх. Вам стоит покопать игровые движки AndEngine, LibGDX или другой. В cocos-2d-android такого точно нету, сразу могу сказать.

Раз уж задели тему контролов: лучшая сторонняя библиотека контролов, которую я видел - это [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) Но мое отношение к ней неоднозначное, да и такого контрола в ней по-моему нет, но стоит держать либу на заметке.

Comment: GreenDroid интересен. Спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите ради интереса еще вот здесь [Android UI Patterns:Open Source UI Libs](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/01/hands-on-open-source-android-ui.html)
Автор рассматривает популярные опен-сурс решения для организации общепринятых UI-паттернов.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на Analog Control у движка [AndEngine](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/).

Тоже очень интересует данная тема. К примеру, у iOS есть замечательный [сайт](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls).